# Modify flip beamer theme

Tags: beamer, themes, mini-frames

Recently I came across `flip beamer theme`.
[You can find it here](http://www.lepp.cornell.edu/~pt267/docs.html)

I didn't like the `current frame/total frames` page numbering style so I added in the `.tex` file the following lines

```
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
\oldmacro\hfill%
\insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
```

but it didn't work. I thought of trying to see what's going on in the `.sty` files. In `beamerouterthemeFlip.sty` I replaced

```
\node at (\paperwidth-5ex,4ex){\small$^\text{\insertframenumber}/_\text{\inserttotalframenumber}$};
```

with

```
 \node at (\paperwidth-5ex,4ex) {\small $\insertframenumber$};
```

and it worked.

[image: changing numbering style]

Now I want to add `smoothbars` on top...The ones with circle...Something like that

[image: circles and smooth bars]

In `.tex` file I added

```
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}
```

but not only it didn't work, it somehow ruined the beauty of the theme.

[image: the loss of beauty]

Is there a way to achieve that? Circles on top without ruinning everything...

I am also trying to add a `logo` but using

```
\logo{\includegraphics[scale=.05]{logo.jpg}}
```

It is not working...

Comment: Concerning your problem with the `smoothbars` theme: Calling `\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}` **before** `\usetheme[...]{Flip}` work for me. Still you will get many `** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.` by XeLaTeX.

Comment: First slide need not have a page number know...How to set that? 
and the first slide need not have a smooth bar also..and I want to change the color of the smooth bar. how to do that? help me@thanos

Answer (score 4):

Logo is inserted with `\insertlogo` macro. For this, you need to uncomment line 171 in `beamerouterthemeFlip.sty`

Comment: Or copy the definition into document preamble.

Comment: First slide need not have a page number know...How to set that?

Comment: and the first slide need not have a smooth bar also..and I want to change the color of the smooth bar. how to do that? help me@cacamilg

Comment: @David I did not understand your question. First, if this answer to your previous question was OK, please accept it. Second, if you have another question, write another question with MWE.

Comment: op is different not me@cacamailg

Comment: @David I did not understand what you mean...